# Swift rotating portrait image without scale

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, image, rotation

I have a problem with swift, I have an app that, when a button is pressed, must rotate an image of 90°, for doing this I use this code

```
extension UIImage {
public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat, flip: Bool) -> UIImage {
    let radiansToDegrees: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
        return $0 * (180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI))
    }
    let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
        return $0 / 180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)
    }

    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))
    let t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(degrees));
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t
    let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
    let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, 0.5 * rotatedSize.width, 0.5 * rotatedSize.height);

    //   // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, degreesToRadians(degrees));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    var yFlip: CGFloat

    if(flip){
        yFlip = CGFloat(-1.0)
    } else {
        yFlip = CGFloat(1.0)
    }

    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, yFlip, -1.0)
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, size.width, size.height), CGImage)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}}
```

with pictures in landscape i haven't any problem but when I try to rotate an image in portrait, on the first press of the button the image is scaled adapting its width to the width of the ImageView, losing his proportions, and without rotate, it is rotated, always with new proportions, only with the second pressure... can anyone help me?

here a screenshot of the starting situation
[image]

after first press
[image]

after second press[image]

Comment: add images please, and tell us what are the constraints you are using on the image if any.

Comment: @DeyaEldeen I've edited the post, I don't use any constraints on the image

Comment: so maybe this is caused by autolayout ?did you use storyboards or you built the interface programattically ?

Comment: @DeyaEldeen I use a storybord